# FInd the intersect between timestamps in Matlab

Tags: matlab, timestamp, intersect

[image: How can I include the purple start in the result in the middle line]

I want to find the intersect between 2 time vectors t1 and t5 which have some gaps marked by the stars as in the figure. Because intersect function in matlab just find exactly value so I have to use ismembertol. My result is the middle line, which is missing the gap information in the t5 vector. How can I achieve this? This is my code:
`

```
tol = 1e-08; Fs = 50;
[a,b] = ismembertol(t1,t5,tol);
tcom15 = t1(a);
t1gap = t1(find(round(diff(t1)* 86400*Fs)>1));
t5gap = t5(find(round(diff(t5)* 86400*Fs)>1));
tcom15gap = tcom15(find(round(diff(tcom15)* 86400*Fs)>1));
figure; plot(t1,2*ones(length(t1),1)); hold on
plot(t5,3*ones(length(t5),1));ylim([1 4])

plot(t1gap,2*ones(length(t1gap),1),':*','MarkerSize',5) 
plot(t5gap,3*ones(length(t5gap),1),':*','MarkerSize',10) 

plot(tcom15,2.5*ones(length(tcom15),1)) 
plot(tcom15gap,2.5*ones(length(tcom15gap),1),':*','MarkerSize',10)
```

Comment: Can you use `ismembertol` with the arguments `t1` and `t5` both ways round? i.e. two seperate calls to the function (`t1` membership in `t5`, and `t5` membership in `t1`), with an "and" requirement for your output?

Comment: yes, I have thought of it as well but I dont know how to perform that. Would you please explain it more ? Thank you

Comment: Something like, `idx = intersect( t1(ismembertol(t1,t5,tol)), t5(ismembertol(t5,t1,tol) )`. I don't know what this looks like, but it should get you close.

Comment: thank you. I have just tried but it doesnot work because of the intersect function, it finds the EXACT number so it turns out there are so many gaps in the common vector. I replace intersect with ismembertol but it returns just the same as I got. It is strange

Comment: Without a [mcve] with example `t1` and `t5`, it's hard to help you more.

Comment: To make Wolfie's statement a bit clearer: provide example data (as little as you can to describe the problem). Also, what do you mean by 'the intersect between 2 time vectors'? What should the output vector look like?